# Too Much gap between x-axis labels and text in Apexchart using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

`When the x-axis labels are rotated at an angle of 45degrees the gap between the labels and title of x -axis drastically increse giving a bad user experience

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nytVz.png)

In this as you can see , when the x-axis labels are not rotated the gap between labels and title is fine , but when it gets rotated the gap increases .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.